# Реализация новостей на сайте и всего остального

Tags: cms

Здравствуйте, нужна некая "основа, ядро, cms" для будущих сайтов. Например чтобы в CMS уже присутствовала возможность создания новостей для главной страницы, некая админ панель, возможность авторизации. Что порекомендуете? Кроме WordPress.

Comment: Drupal хороший вариант

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ModX, на нём придётся поучиться работать, но это того стоит. Даст возможность делать сайты от блогов до магазинов (это CMF)

Typo3 довольно неплохая CMS. На ней, я бы рарзмещал небольшие блоги, сайты до 3000 страниц, но это чисто моё мнение.

Drupal, если вам нужно делать какую-то соц. сеть или что угодно другое, где пользователь сам будет создавать контент.

Joomla использовать в 2018 уже не стоит.